# Hair particles (eyelashes) sticking together on a mirrored model

Tags: particles, mirror-modifier, particle-edit-mode

I'm working on the eyelashes of my mirrored character.
I drew weight paint on the left eye with mirror mod so the weight was applied to both eyes.

However, the eyelashes were only applied on the side I painted.

[image]

but then when I go to Particles Edit mode, the eyelashes go thru my face, the left eyelashes connected to the particles of the right eyelashes in the image below.
[image]

I've searched this online, and most solutions of other similar cases are about the position of the mirror mod and the particle mod but my mirror mod is already on top of the particle mod.

I'm very confused about this problem, can anybody help please?
Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thank you so much!
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug, better apply the mirror modifier.

Comment: Not sure if that helps but the *Subdivision Surface* modifier should go last for sure. Move it down to the bottom of the stack else you will get different results for the particles in the viewport and the render because of the different sub-division levels (1 and 2).